# In java, why new operator not used before data type to allocate memory?

Tags: java, new-operator

If we need `new` operator to allocate the memory for an object, then why don't we use it 
before data types to allocate the memory?

```
class-name class-var =  new class-name();
new int a;
```

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: Is my question wrong why down-voted me, my reputation was 11, now it is 9, its hard to make reputation, but easy to loose. :D

Comment: @user2849331 no, some jokers are trolling and down-voting everything in this thread without explanation nor reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Because [James Gosling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gosling)  said so.... (or [Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/) said so). Really, it is mostly a question of language design, not technical laws.
2. `javac` hides these semantics from you and does what is called boxing / unboxing (and does it automatically). Those types can exist as `values` or as "objects" (typically implemented with a heap). When a context requires an object reference, javac emits a box instruction to move the `int` value into an object wrapper (int -> Integer) and passes a `reference value`. Many low level JVM opcodes are built to handle scalar values as are some built to handle reference values (or just references).

One prime example is storing an `int` into a collection. It gets boxed.

But in the end, asking why a language does what it does syntactically is just like asking an artist why he painted a painting thus. Just because. Languages are designed somewhat by whim and emotion, but in Java's case, the syntax of `new` was inherited from C++ so the whim might have been [Bjarne Stroustrup's](http://www.stroustrup.com/) instead. Also consider that Scala is also a JVM language, yet it has very different syntax for some common ideas.

The key here is the compiler writer can make a decision tomorrow that "NEW Java" will be a new language that requires `NEW` in all caps in front of all types. It could be implemented without affecting the semantics of the language, whatsoever.

Granted, there is sound design and consistency behind the choices, but the choices are still just choices. In this case, the choice clearly indicates that an `int` is a primitive type, and `new` only returns objects, not primitives. So it is a good choice of syntax.

Comment: could it be a reason that memory is allocated to primitive data type at compile time, whereas new operator allocates at run time.

Comment: No. The choice is mostly one of syntax (albeit syntax for sake of design). The size of most other object types are also known at compile time. That isn't the difference. The compiler writer can decide to make `new` optional in this case, and simply ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

Java has two kinds of types: *primitive* data types and *reference* data types.

`int` is a primitive data type. A reference data type references an instance of a class , or an instance of an array.

For primitive data types, the `new` operator is not used. Primitive data types are always passed *by value*. For reference data types, the reference is passed by value, but you can have many references pointing to the same object or array.

So if you change anything in the object that your reference points to, all other references also see the change. For primitive data types, this doesn't happen.

More information about primitive and reference data types:

[Chapter 4 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html)

Comment: "Primitive data types are always passed by value.", well, everything in Java is passed by value, including Objects. It's just that when you pass an object into a method, you are passing the value of the reference. ;)

Comment: @SnakeDoc that's incorrect. Objects are passed by reference, references to objects are passed by value. Please read my whole answer.

Comment: sorry, but Java is explicitly only pass-by-value. You pass the value of the reference, but not the reference itself as-in a pointer in C. There is a difference. I refer you to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: Please read about Java **reference types** (why do you think they are called that?) on in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3) and then come back here. The Java Language Specification is the authoritative source on the Java Language.

Comment: If you are still trying to argue Java is pass-by-reference with Objects, you are flatly wrong. I think you should read the JLS. Here is yet another article proving you wrong: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm  -- and another: http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=61622  -- I can go all night if you insist.

Comment: @SnakeDoc, Erwin : I think you both agree. Objects are never passed by value, but references to those objects are passed by value. You are  saying the same thing ...

Answer (score 0):

this is mostly due to how compilers and/or interpreters will read this source. Basically you must tell the compiler/interpreter what type of object it is working with prior to assigning memory to it. This is the same in most languages, including C and Java. You basically tell the compiler/interpreter the type of object, the name of that object, then the assignment operation. `new` is not always to the right of the assignment operator, as-in you could be copying/cloning an existing variable name/handle of the same object type.

The reason Java primitives don't need the `new` operator is as @pep said, the language/platform already knows the defined size of that type. `int` will always be 32 bytes in Java, but `MyCustomClass` might not be.

Comment: @leo no, someone is playing a game. not offering a better explanation or at least a comment, but just a drive-by down-vote.

Comment: seriously, stop the down-votes unless you have a better explanation.